# Bound a Leaflet map to many layers

Tags: dictionary, leaflet, bounds

I have a leaflet map with many layers and each layer has many objects. Is there a way to fit the map bounds so that all objects in all layers are visible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're using or could switch to [FeatureGroup](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#featuregroup), which is extended from [LayerGroup](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#layergroup), you have the getBounds method which would return the bounds of all the layers/features in your group. Those you could use with fitBounds method of your mapinstance.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It only took a line of code after all!

Comment: No problem :) If this is the correct answer could you please accept it as such? [http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)

Comment: I came across another problem. What if a layer is empty? The featureGroup cannot be created and there are no bounds to fit...

Comment: That's kind of beyond the scope of this current question and hard to answer without some code and a testcase/plunkr. I'de suggest to open a new question, comments aren't fit for this.

Comment: Oh, my error, the layer, was not empty it was undefined.

Answer (score -1):

```
map.addLayer("your layer name");
```